# How can I duplicate VB.NET 'Import Namespace' functionality in a C# project?

Tags: c#, vb.net

In a VB.NET project, on the Add Reference screen it is possible to 'Import Namespaces'. Namespaces added like this are globally declared so that you do not have to add an `Import Namespace` line to each file.

This allows, in rare cases, a VB developer to share/link one code file to two projects and have a different namespace in each project resolve to the same classes in a third project. This solves a particular problem I have with references to WCF services via other WCF services that is caused by our architecture.

I now have to use this code, suitably translated, in a C# project and I couldn't find a way to add a namespace at a global level because in C# the `using` directive, like the `Import` statement applies *only* to the file it is in.

Is it possible to duplicate the 'Import Namespaces' functionality of a VB.NET project in a C# project?

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ Could you elaborate on how that solves the problem?

Comment: I think he means it ironically, as in 'resharper solves all problems'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only in ASP.NET can you do that. There you can do the global imports using the web.config file, like so:

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Data.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.IO"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>  
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Cool! My C# project is actually an aSP.NET one so this will work nicely